# Render Random Item from State React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given some items stored in state, I want to be able to click a button and display a random item from that array. So far it only works on the first click and then it displays the same one letter after the first click.

What exactly is going on?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      notes: ['hey', 'yo', 'sup'],
      clicked: false
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true, 
      notes: this.state.notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
this.state.notes.length)]
    })
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Note</button>
        <h1>{this.state.clicked ? this.state.notes : ''}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what did you expect to happen? this.state.notes is an array, but then in your handleClick function you're making notes a string

Comment: Cause `"h"[0]` is `"h"` ?

Comment: You REWRITE notes by one random note. Add one more field f e randomNode: null and write random note in it and display it in render().

Answer (score 2):

Add selected note handling

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      notes: ['hey', 'yo', 'sup'],
      selectedNote: null,
      clicked: false
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true, 
      selectedNote: this.state.notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
this.state.notes.length)]
    })
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Note</button>
        <h1>{this.state.clicked && this.state.selectedNote}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `notes` array in state in your `handleClick` method.  Try using a different key (something like `activeNote`) in `handleClick`, then use that in your render method rather than `this.state.notes`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Could you give me a little code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I solved it.

I ended up adding another state key `randomWord` and setting it equal to `''`.

I then set the state of `randomWord` to that of `this.state.notes` when randomized.

Finally, I rendered `this.state.randomWord`

No clue if that's the correct approach but it's a working solution, lol.